# How to call another project's method where DI is implemented

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, containers

I think I implemented a poor architecture. Try to follow me on this please.

I have **project1** that is a simple scraper. Whenever it receive a response from its scraping process, it want to save the scraped data into the database. It has its own DI container.

I have **project2** which is the one responsible for executing DB migrations and I placed also the logic to access and modify the database in here. I wanted to keep all the logic to manage the DB in one place only. It has its own DI container.

Finally, I have **project3** which is an API that whenever asked, serves the data stored in the DB. It has its own DI container.

As you can see **project2** is in the middle, it gets used both by the scraper project when saving data and the API project for serving the data.
In **project2** my DI registration looks like this:

```
private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IConfiguration Configuration)
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

    // Inject IOptions<T>
    services.AddOptions();
    var dbSettings = Configuration.GetSection("Settings");
    services.Configure<DbSettings>(dbSettings);

    return services;
}
```

What it does is that looks into the appsettings (there is only a connectionString towards the database saved) and prepares *IOption* to be injected where needed.
So in **project2** there is a for example a method to check if the DB is empty.

```
public class DbClient : IDbClient
{
    private readonly IOptions<DbSettings> _dbSettings;
    public DbClient(IOptions<DbSettings> dbSettings)
    {
        _dbSettings = dbSettings;
    }

    public bool IsDbEmpty()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_dbSettings.Value.ConnectionString))
        {
            var isEmpty = connection.QueryFirst<string>("SELECT COUNT(1) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Test)");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Guess where the problem is? Whenever I try to call this method from either **project1** (the scraper) or **project3** (the API) the *IOptions* is not injected, because I haven't called the container of **project2**. How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does "project2" needs it's own container? It sounds like it should simply be a class library that's used by project1 and project3

Comment: @devNull not necessarily.. but how else do I pass to the methods the connection string otherwise if not with the IOption (and therefore DI) pattern?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have your shared project ("**project2**") expose some functionality for configuration that can be used by consuming applications ("**project1**" and "**project3**").

With .NET Core, you can do this by defining `IServiceCollection` extension methods in your shared project ("**project2**"):

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddProject2(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        var dbSettings = configuration.GetSection("Settings");
        services.Configure<DbSettings>(dbSettings);

        return services;
    }
}
```

And then calling this from the startup of the consuming projects ("**project1**" and "**project3**"):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddProject2(Configuration);

    ...
}
```

---

Note that you can then define the configuration required for "**project2**" within any project that is consuming it.

Comment: Mmmm in this way it won't work yet.. reason is that when you call the extension method from for example **project1** you will have to pass the IConfiguration.. and in that case the IConfiguration that you pass are the ones of **project1** which are not containing the appsettings of project2..

Comment: @Tarta hence my comment "Note that you can then define the configuration required for "project2" within any project that is consuming it."

Comment: That's generally how configuration works. If those settings are meant to be "configurable", then you can simply hardcode them in the `AddProject2` method

Comment: Oh now I understand it! But in this way I don't keep anymore the single responsibility that I was trying to achieve by keeping roles separated. I mean that I wanted to keep everything that relates the DB in the **project2**.. in this way now I have to define the connection string also in the other projects

Comment: @Tarta Potentially. Although there are solutions to that problem as well, such as [creating shared settings](https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: In the class where you define the extension method, there you can have static constructor having IConfiguration of Project2 injected and then this could be saved in a private property of the class which could be further referenced inside extension method.